# How to manually update a gem in the capstrino environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a codebase, which is used as a gem in the older codebase. After deployment we see that, the older code in the gem is getting executed. Now we want to manually update the gem in the server

here is what capistrino is doing

```
bundler:install
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.0 do bundle install --path /home/deployer/bla/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
      01 Warning, new version of rvm available '1.28.0', you are using older version '1.27.0'.
      01 You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
      01 You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
```

So I went into the bundle folder and I did 
`bundle update gem_name`. 
It said it could not find the gemfile. And the contents of the bundle folder is just ruby. Is there a way that I can manually update the gem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler doesn't work that way. Even if you updated the gem, if your Gemfile/Gemfile.lock still reference the old version, that's the one that will be loaded. If it's not available, then your app won't boot.

If you want to update the gem in your production environment, you need to run `bundle update gem_name` inside your app directory, where the Gemfile is located. Assuming you haven't picked a too-specific version in your Gemfile, this will modify your Gemfile.lock and install the new gem.

Comment: So you mean to say, my gems are installed where? not as per the cap setup I have shown in the question?

Comment: They'll be installed to wherever you instruct bundler to install them, but you can't then go into that directory and still use `bundle`. Bundler operates on the Gemfile, it needs to be run from where your Gemfile is located.